# Camel IMAP endpoint: "FailedToCreateRouteException ... Failed to resolve endpoint: ... due to: host must be specified and not empty"

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-mail

The following is in my POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0<version>
    </dependency>
```

My endpoint configuration derived from https://camel.apache.org/mail.html, *Samples* section:

```
    ...
    from("imap://{{mail_user}}@{{imaps_server}} password={{mail_password}}&unseen=true&consumer.delay={{poll_interval}}")
    ...
```

Which results in:

```
...
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:
Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[imap://{{mail_user}}@{{imaps_server}} pa...
because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
imap://********@mail.upcmail.at%20password=********&unseen=true&consumer.delay=10000
due to: host must be specified and not empty
...
```

but `mail.upcmail.at` ist the host, isn't it? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a typo in your post ? The question mark (?) Is missing in your uri.
This should be:
from("imap://{{mail_user}}@{{imaps_server}}?password=...")

Comment: Not in my post but on the doc page I mentioned. I took this literally. With `?` it works now. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=user@gmail.com&password=AppPassword&unseen=true&delay=6000")    
    .to("log:newmail");
  }
```